# Import a list from a different file

Tags: python-2.7

Is there a way I can import a list from a different Python file?  For example if I have a list:

`list1  = ['horses', 'sheep', 'cows', 'chickens', 'dog']`

Can I import this list into other files? I know to import other functions you do

`from FileName import DefName`

This is a user defined list and I don't want to have the user input the same list a million times.

Just a few maybes as to how this could be done:

`from FileName import ListName` or put all the lists into a function and then import the definition name

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll just export the lists in a file. Therefore every piece of code can read it.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to dump that list into a temp file, and read it from your other python script.

Another option (if one python script calls the other), is to pass the list as an argument (e.g. using `sys.argv[1]` and `*args`, etc).

Comment: How would I pass the list as an argument?